# Navbar blocking click-ability of links inside

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to make a simple navbar with some clickable links inside. However, right now I can't actually click the contents of the Navbar. I have a feeling the Navbar is "blocking" the accessibility of the links inside, but long story short I want to actually be able to click the links. I've attached snippets of my `html` and `scss` below. Where did I go wrong?

```html
<nav class="cool-navbar">
        <div class="left-buttons">
            <a class="cool-link">Sammy Al Hashemi</a>
        </div>
        <div class="middle-spacer"></div>
        <div class="right-buttons">
            <a class="cool-link">Projects</a>
            <a class="cool-link">Contact</a>
        </div>
</nav>
```

```css
.cool-navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100vw;
  height: $navbar-height;
  background: inherit;

  .left-buttons {
    width: auto;
  }
  .middle-spacer {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .right-buttons {
    width: auto;
  }

  .left-buttons .cool-link,
  .right-buttons .cool-link {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px 35px 12px 35px;
    background: inherit;
    font-family: $font-stack;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: $secondary-font-size;
    color: $secondary-color;
    animation: cool-button-entrance 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 backwards;
    -webkit-animation: cool-button-entrance 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 backwards;
  }
}

.cool-navbar::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: $secondary-color solid 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: $navbar-height;
  animation: cool-border-animation 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 both;
  -webkit-animation: cool-border-animation 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `<a> tag` links haven't been given a hypertext reference. It can be set with the href attribute like so: `<a href="link goes here">` You can set the reference to '#' as a placeholder until you have a link to place:

```
<nav class="cool-navbar">
    <div class="left-buttons">
        <a href="#" class="cool-link">Sammy Al Hashemi</a>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-spacer"></div>
    <div class="right-buttons">
        <a href="#" class="cool-link">Projects</a>
        <a href="#" class="cool-link">Contact</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I appreciate it! Unfortunately, I don't believe this fixes the issue. You are right about adding the `href`, however, something still appears to be blocking the ability to click it.

Comment: Figured it out though! It was because the `::before` pseudoelement was hovering over the link, blocking it being clicked. I instead set its `top: $navbar-height` and removed its `height`. This stopped causing it to block. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! It was because the `::before` pseudoelement was hovering over the link, blocking it being clicked. I instead set its `top: $navbar-height` and removed its `height`. This stopped causing it to block.